Чего плохого в подобной обертке над string?
Задавал вопрос Нарушение принципов SOLID и другое
Один из комментариев, если я правильно понял, не хорошо создавать класс под одно только свойство string
Комментарий: это бесполезная обертка над строкой, смысл?
Типа такого:
public class RawStackOverflowLink
{
    public string Link { get; set; }
}

Для меня это, cсылка с мусором, типа такого "325230fkewf ru.stackoverflow.com/users/373567/ odwf3430"
Ноги растут из БД RawStackOverflowLinks[ID,Link]
Для себя выделяю удобство, что в независимости от количества свойств, так просто могу вставить объект в БД сколько бы свойств у объекта небыло, из за этого по сути и привязался к такому подходу.
    protected async Task InsertAsync(T entity) 
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        string query = $"INSERT INTO {_tableName} ({string.Join(", ", properties.Select(p => p.Name))}) Values ({string.Join(", ", properties.Select(p => $"@{p.Name}"))})";
        Dictionary<string, object> parameters = [];

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            parameters.Add($"@{property.Name}", property.GetValue(entity));
        }

        await ExecuteNonQueryAsync(query, parameters);
    }

Чего плохого в подобной обертке над string ?

Не вижу здесь никакой обертки, а то что у вас объект с одним полем, не делает его обёрткой.

Если RawStackOverflowLink - это дата модель для Storage, то это нормально иметь под него отдельный класс. Другое дело, что у дата моделей обычно есть и другие поля в базе. Например, ID, или ReceivedDateTime (дата получения этой сырой ссылки).

С вашим подходом к Storage есть проблемы. Самая главная из них - это string query = $"INSERT INTO ...". Ваш код уязвим к Sql Injection. Вы пытаетесь заново изобрести велосипед. Попробуйте почитать про ORM и как это правильно приготовить в C# (например. c Dapper)

И вообще если тут одно поле, то возможно проще было сам класс унаследовать от string и вообще не делать в нём полей ))

@AndreiKhotko откуда возьмётся инъекция-то, если в запрос попадают исключительно имена свойств объекта?

@PavelMayorov верно, я невнимательно прочитал код

В вашем предыдущем вопрос ни слова не было про базу, рефлексию, и так далее, зато было что-то такое: DefineType(StackOverflowLink stackOverflowLink) {if (Regex.IsMatch(stackOverflowLink.Link, ...)) { return ..; } } - вот взгляните на этот код и скажи, зачем тут вообще класс StackOverflowLink, который в себе содержит только одно свойство с типом string? Почему не сделать просто TypeStackOverflowLink DefineType (string link) { ... Regex.IsMatch(link, ...)}? Вот про это я вам и говорил, что подобными классами вы перемудрили, они бесполезны. Но если там база и рефлексия, то да, они нужны.

Правда, согласен с комментарием выше, вы тогда в таком случае изобретаете велосипед, делая некую динамичную базу, которая может все и вся. А вот это уже как по мне, плохо. Допустим, ваш метод открыт, он принимает все, вы можете запихнуть туда любой похожий класс и будет у вас в базе не то, чего вы ожидаете. Мой вам совет, возьмите готовые решения для базы и используйте их, а не изобретайте свои костыли. Ну а на будущее, если хотите получить внятный ответ, то давайте весь код, а не огрызки, которые кажутся в данном контексте бесполезными, когда на деле они используются совершенно для другого.

@EvgeniyZ Понял, принял, спасибо! EvgeniyZ, сложно без огрызгов и псевдокода, реальный код не выложишь, во первых он сильно больше, а во вторых хз), я думал многое запихнуть, пол дня писал вопрос, потом понял что ну нет, такое всех спугнёт... Стёр и выложил огрызок выдуманный на примере StackOverflow. Буду стараться лучше формулировать. А вот про велосипед, как его не создавать ?  Вот теперь может и не буду) Я загуглил "Как работать с БД" Увидел несколько примеров, запросы показались проще всего, их и взял за пример, а рефлексия как то сама прилипла)

Почитайте справку SO, там есть пункт про "Минимальный и самодостаточный пример" - вот его и делайте. Создаете голый проект и в него добавляете минимально всего того, что требуется для вашего вопроса. Я уверен, что там будет довольно небольшой кусок кода, который спокойно будет читаться на SO. Потратите чуть больше времени, зато не будет такой вот путаницы. Что касается базы - помните, почти для всего есть готовые решения, которые зачастую куда лучше того, что вы напишете самостоятельно. Вы сейчас работаете с базой на низком уровне, когда есть всякие EF и его аналоги. Вот его и советую учить.

@EvgeniyZ Спасибо!
